# Postcode validation not working with postcode ranges

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to create a postcode validation in woocommerce.

I can´t make my query look into a range interval like 10000-000...15000-000.

My query works fine with simple postcodes(10000-000 or 11001-001), but does not work with the range of postcodes.

```
 global $wpdb;
    $tabela_cep = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations';
    $query = "SELECT location_code FROM $tabela_cep WHERE location_code = %s LIMIT 1";
    $resultado = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $cep));
```

I don´t know how woocommerce store all the ranges from all shipping zones in database.

I´ve tried "between" sintax to filter the fields location*code and location*code2, but i m not sure if this is the correct field name/table name or even is there another way to achieve this.

```
global $wpdb; 
$tabela_cep = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations'; 
$query = "SELECT location_code FROM $tabela_cep WHERE %s BETWEEN CAST(location_code AS UNSIGNED) AND CAST(location_code2 AS UNSIGNED) LIMIT 1";
$resultado = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $cep));
```

Thank You

Comment: Normalize your codes from string to numeric value then use common range checking (WHERE BETWEEN). Now your CAST() simply truncates your value by cutting off trail substring starting from first non-numeric char (see SHOW WARNINGS).

Comment: @Akina post codes _are not_ numbers.

Comment: @CBroe It seems that my "from string to numeric" claims the same.. Or you mean that the postcodes may contain, for example, letters? if so than this is OP mistake, sample data incorrectness.

Comment: _"Or you mean that the postcodes may contain, for example, letters?"_ - or they might for example start with a leading `0` in some countries, which actual numbers never do.

Comment: @CBroe Leading zeros are not a problem until '123-456' and '0123-456' are existing different codes. Anycase the code can be normalized not to a number but to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can help, but there is already a core WooCommerce function called wc_postcode_location_matcher() that checks if a given postcode is within a range of postcodes.

You first need to calculate the $postcode_locations:

```
global $wpdb;
$postcode_locations = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT zone_id, location_code FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations WHERE location_type = 'postcode';" );
```

Then you need the $country, so if you're on the checkout page:

```
$country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
```

...or if you're validating an order:

```
$country = $order->get_billing_country();
```

Then you're good to go:

```
$matches = wc_postcode_location_matcher( $postcode, $postcode_locations, 'zone_id', 'location_code', $country );
return $matches; // if empty there is no match
```